# How to retreive a specific element from a vector and assign it to a variable?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class called Student with the following value constructor:

```cpp
Student::Student(const string &id) : id_(id){}
```

And in the main.cpp I have:

```cpp
shared_ptr<Student> s1(new Student("st1"));
shared_ptr<Student> s2(new Student("st2"));
shared_ptr<Student> s3(new Student("st3"));

vector<Student> vect;

vect.push_back(s1); 
vect.push_back(s2); 
vect.push_back(s3);
```

Then I intend to retreive a student with id "st2" from `vect` and assign it to a variable, how do I do that?

Comment: Aren't you just overwriting the variable `s1` each time in the first 3 lines? And shouldn't your vector be `vector<shared_ptr<Student>>`? Is `id_` private? Is there a getter function to test for its value?

Comment: @AllanCameron I fixed the code as it was a typo.